# Symbolic Integration of a Specific Integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I'm trying to compute the integral $$\int_{\delta n!/n}^{1/n}\int_{\alpha_{n-1}}^{1/n} \cdots \int_{\alpha_2}^{1/n} \frac{1}{x_2\cdots x_n}dx_2\cdots dx_n$$ where $$\alpha_k = \frac{\delta n!}{n^{n-k+1}}\frac{1}{\prod_{k+1}^n x_i}$$ As I was running into trouble with actually evaluating this thing by hand, I thought I'd be able to do it with *Mathematica*.

In particular, I was looking to compute this for $n = 3$, then $n=4$, then $n=5$, and so on until I could see a pattern. I tried shoving this into *Mathematica* but it isn't working whatsoever. It doesn't appear that I've typed in anything incorrectly so I'm confused why it isn't evaluating. Would appreciate some help. Here is the code so far.

```
Integrate[ 1/(x2 x3),
           {x3, d (n - 1)!, 1/n}, {x2, (d n!/(n^{n - 1}))(1/x3), 1/n}]
```

EDIT: As the comments have suggested, some motivation on where this comes from may be of interest. This integral is relevant in a certain situation related to high-dimensional convex geometry. Consider the $n$-cube which we will call $C_n$. We will only concern ourselves with the corner of the $n$-cube which is situated at the origin. Chop off a volume $\delta$ in the corner of the cube so that the resulting shape is a simplex. Take the center of gravity $\textbf{g}$ of the chopped off area. If you chop off all possible volumes $\delta$ where the resulting shape is a simplex and take the center of gravity, then the center of gravities form a curve that looks like $\frac{1}{x_2\cdots x_n}$ (with some factors which I won't mention). This integral computes the volume difference of this curve and the $n$-cube in the corner of the $n$-cube. So the $n$ here refers to the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\delta$ refers to the area that you are chopping off. $\delta$ is bounded above by $\text{vol}(C_n)/2$.

Comment: I'm going to say that your nickname is discouraging from answering any questions even though they might be interesting. You should start with `With[{n = 2}, Integrate[
  1/(x2*x3), {x3, d*(n - 1)!, 1/n}, {x2, (d*n!/(n^{n - 1}))*(1/x3), 1/n}]]`, then it clearer how to tackle a general case.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without assigning a value to $n$ or will it take too long?

Comment: There are many ways of calculating such a multiple integral. I have an approach for a general $n$, however not an efficient one and so I wouldn't like demonstrating it.  On the other hand I find this question interesting and I recommend to edit your question including information on motivations of calculating these integrals (statistical physics?) and neccesary assumptions on $\delta$. Such details make a question much more likely to find good answers.

Comment: I have added some additional details on this question if you are still interested. If you would like some more, please let me know and I can refer you to the correct sources.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways of calculating symbolic integrals for a general $n$, nonetheless I'll describe perhaps the most straightforword one. I guesss that there might be a more efficient way, but it would be instructive to take a direct approach.

Let's define $\alpha_k$, I'll use a symbol `a` in order to underline that it depends on $n$ as well (`/; cond` denotes appropriate conditions cond to restrict a domain):

```
a[k_, n_] /; 1 < k <= n && (k | n) \[Element] Integers :=
  ( d Factorial[n])/(n^(n - k + 1) Product[x[i], {i, k + 1, n}])
```

Now we can define the integral:

```
int[n_] /; n \[Element] Integers && n >= 2 := 
  Integrate[ 1/Product[ x[i], {i, 2, n}], ##, 
             Assumptions -> 0 < d < 1/Factorial[n + 1]]& @@ 
    Table[{x[i], a[i, n], 1/n}, {i, Range[n, 2, -1]}]
```

I included an assumption on `d` to make an integral calculated in an unconditional way.

```
{#, int[#]} & /@ {3, 4, 5} // Column // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

It appears that the timing of this symbolic calculation increases roughly  exponentially with of  `n` and so there might be a more efficient approach, e.g.

```
AbsoluteTiming[i5 = int[5]] // First
```

> ```
>  5.95725
> ```

while `int[6]` takes almost 1 minute on my computer.
Let's plot how `i5` behaves on `d`:

```
Plot[ i5, {d, 0, 1/6!}, PlotStyle -> Thick, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

@Artes supplied all of the heavy lifting.  Here is how to take those functions to find the general result.

Some simplification of the integrals can be made by applying the following rules:

```
rules = {Log[a_ b_] -> Log[a] + Log[b], Log[d^k_] -> k Log[d]};

Table[{n, (int[n] //. rules // Expand) // FullSimplify}, {n, 3, 6}]
```

[image: Table of simplified results]

We see the pattern and the general form is

```
(-Log[d n!])^(-1 + n)/(n - 1)!
```

or

$$\frac{(-\log (d n!))^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I apologize for the late reply. I, in fact, managed to get this exact answer after bearing down and computing the integrals for n = 1,...,6 by hand but this is a very nice and direct way to do it which would have saved quite a bit of time.

Comment: Also, if you don't mind me asking, why does Mathematica not handle the rules $\ln(ab) = \ln(a) + \ln(b), \ln(a^k) = k\ln(a)$ already? Considering Artes's answer, it would not be clear at all what the expression should be but your answer makes it extraordinarily clear.

Comment: I think *Mathematica* doesn't automatically use those rules because their use depends on the values of $a$ and $b$.  Is $\log((-3)(-4))=\log(12)$ or $\log(-3)+\log(-4)=2 i \pi +\log (3)+\log (4)$ ?  Using appropriate `Assumptions` on $a$ and $b$ might allow the usual rules to be applied.